# How can we know the geometry of a blob detected by OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, connected-components

I am performing blob analysis using `connectedComponentsWithStats`, which returns elementary statistics about the blobs (AABB and area). It is also possible to compute geometric moments.

Anyway, I need to compute my own features and for this I need the detailed geometry, be it a chain of outline pixels, a run-lengh-coded description or similar.

I know that the contours can be obtained by other means (`findContours`), but I would like to know if the connected components engine can help me achieve my goal or if it is a black box forever.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of connected components you may also use blob detector mentioned [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/)

It provides some information on the shape and geometry of blob

For geometric moments you will have to compute contours.

I am not sure what do you mean by connected components being a black box.